# Java ignores classpath

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm writing a java program which uses the Oracle JDBC driver. I've set it up in my classpath. When I run the program inside my IDE (added as jdbc as library) the program runs fine. When I try to deploy it, it totaly ignores the listing in classpath and gives me a NoClassDefFoundError.

I want to use the client's JDBC driver (the one installed) and don't supply my own. I package the program from JDeveloper, deployment as JAR File.

Running with: java -jar test.jar

When I put the library in %JAVA_HOME%/lib/ext it works properly.

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us how your running the file on the command line?

Comment: How **exactly** are you deploying it? How do you package it? How do you launch it? Note that if you're using the `-jar` switch, then any classpath specified on the command line and in environment variables will be ignored. **Only** the `Class-Path` attribute of the manifest will be relevant.

Comment: Then how do i set the Class-Path so it will look in my environment classpath? Or can i run a jar other than java -jar?

Comment: Just supply your jar with your app. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Nishant Maybe it is, however java has a classpath and the installer of oracle supplies a working jdbc with every installation. We tend to use the already installed jdbc from the classpath.

Comment: As the others note, check the manifest's Class-Path, and since you seem to want to use the predeployed JDBC jar from Oracle, then check your environment variable as well, since if you're not using the manifest, then you are using it (as you did not supply any values on the command line). Linux: `echo $CLASSPATH` Windows: `echo %CLASSPATH%` . If the Oracle JAR is not in your manifest, or in the environment variable, then your JAR won't know where to find it except checking in Java's standard location (as you noted), which is not good practice.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you run with `java -jar`, the classpath is ignored.

You need to use the `Class-Path` manifest property.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

> You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes the following form:
>
> `Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name`

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/linux/java.html

> **-jar**
>
> ...
>
> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Comment: +1 Here's a handy [utility](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto) to view a JAR's manifest _in situ_.

Comment: However i want to use a jar from the current environment's classpath and not to include it in my project. Isn't it possible at all to use a jar from classpath when using `-jar` function?

Comment: You can always create your own classloader with its own class path.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html

Comment: @Ferdy: no, as I said in my comment: **either** the `Class-Path` of your .jar file is inspected (if you use the `-jar` switch) **or** the classpath on the command line/environment variable is used. There's **no** built-in **way** to use both. And: the point of having the `CLASSPATH` variable is **only** to make starting with Java easier. Pretty soon you'll find out that you'll want a build system that handles the classpath at build-time and a module system (or even just a start script) that handles the classpath at runtime.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: As you earlier specified the `-jar` ignores the environment classpath; How can i look for a jdbc driver class when it ignores the environment classpath? Or is it best practise just to supply the jdbc driver?

Comment: @Ferdy: either load it dynamically (if you know its location) by instanciating your own `URLClassLoader` (it not that hard), or redistribute it with your app and put it on your `Class-Path` (note that you'll have to check the license to see if that's legal).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: In my opinion this totally beats the purpose of having a classpath if you have to load it manually using a URLClassLoader... Then you'll have to know the location of the jar you want to include, instead of the JVM solving this problem for you... And Class-Path doesnt look outside its own comfy project folder; So i'll have to ask the user for the location of the JDBC driver? The issue is we don't know which version of Oracle database the user has. Loading this from the classpath gives us the advantage that the user gets an compatible version (usually supplied with the database).

Comment: @Ferdy: I don't want to discuss the philosophical implications of that design decision now. It's as it is and we have to make do with it. Note that your approach also has a sever drawback: you assume that the machine you run your Java code on has the Oracle database (or at least the JDBC drivers) installed. This is not necessarily true, why shouldn't the Java client be able to connect to a remote DB?